# Assert seems to evaluate the return string even on a pass

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have an assert method which is checking to see if an array is empty or null. This check is working fine and when I expect it to be null or empty the test passes. The issue is that I have a string to show when the test fails that prints the to string of the array.

```
Assert.True(list == null || list.Count < 1, $"Printing array {list.ToString()}");
```

This method is causing an exception to be thrown because the string is being evaluated for a null list even though the assert passes and the string should not be used. Why is the string still evaluated?

Comment: You don't need to call `ToString()` on interpolated variables.

Comment: The remark about `ToString()` is legit, and if you wanted to show list elements count instead (like `list.Count`), you could use _null-conditional operator_ `?.` (like `$"List size {list?.Count}"`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling a method will evaluate all of its parameters before the call happens.

Before `Assert.True()` even runs, it will evaluate its string to pass the parameter.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I always forget Assert does not act like a ? statement.